# How to display the size of a mailbox in imapsync (without migrating it)?

Tags: imapsync

I only want to calculate how much space the mailbox has, I don't want to migrate. Is there a way to know the space with imapsync?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you specifically want to use imapsync to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use --justfoldersizes and the same account as source and destination.

https://imapsync.lamiral.info/FAQ.d/FAQ.Folders_Sizes.txt

```
=======================================================================
Q. How can I know the size of all folders before launching a sync?

R. Use --justfoldersizes option.

With the --justfoldersizes option, imapsync evaluates and displays the 
folders sizes on both sides and then exits without doing any transfer.
Example:

  imapsync ... --justfoldersizes

=======================================================================
```